# How to scan the barcode of format PDF 417 using zxing app in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing, barcode-scanner

How do i scan the barcode of format PDF417 ? Do i need to pass intent extras? 
(Note : Zxing barcode app is already installed in my device). Please help me.
Here is my code for using Zxing barcode scanner from my application using Intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
 intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
 intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, MY_ACTIVITY_CONSTANT);
```

Comment: IF you get any Info let me know.. Thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"PRODUCT_MODE" will never work as PDF417 is not a product barcode format. You need to set "SCAN_FORMATS" to "PDF_417" instead. However you probably will find it difficult to scan PDF417 in general. [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) will read it better and responds to these intents.

Answer (score 0):

with the mit app inventor 2, with a barcodescanner object you can do it.

Install in the device the ZXing barcode reader, then goto config and enable pdf417 format (it comes disabled by default) and then download or program any barcode reading app with external barcode reader. Works fine.